# Swift unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value WebView

Tags: webview, swift3

I am using Swift3 and trying to load a local html file.

```
    let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html")
    let htmlString = try? String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString!, baseURL: nil)
```

running in to an error
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Anytime you say `!` you are _asking_ to crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to handle the exception thrown by String method as:

```
let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html")

do {
    let htmlString = try String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
} catch {
    // handle exception
}
```